# $_SERVER headers are missing in PHP but present in Python

Tags: php, python, apache, ip

I'm behind a transparent proxy which always adds the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR header.

When I dump the headers out using PHP the header is missing. But Python works.. lol

Python:

```
remote_addr = os.environ.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', os.environ.get('REMOTE_ADDR', ''))
```

PHP:

```
print_r($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
print_r($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

---- EDIT: Added more info on configs below ------

PHP Version: `5.2.16`

PHP Configure Command:

`'./configure' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-exif' '--enable-fastcgi' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--enable-libxml' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-pdo=shared' '--enable-soap' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sqlite-utf8' '--enable-wddx' '--enable-zip' '--prefix=/usr' '--with-curl=/opt/curlssl/' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-gd' '--with-gettext' '--with-imap=/opt/php_with_imap_client/' '--with-imap-ssl=/opt/openssl' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-kerberos' '--with-libexpat-dir=/usr' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2/' '--with-mcrypt=/opt/libmcrypt/' '--with-mhash=/opt/mhash/' '--with-mime-magic' '--with-mysql=/usr' '--with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' '--with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config' '--with-openssl=/opt/openssl' '--with-openssl-dir=/opt/openssl' '--with-pcre-regex=/opt/pcre' '--with-pdo-mysql=shared' '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-pspell' '--with-sqlite=shared' '--with-tidy=/opt/tidy/' '--with-ttf' '--with-xmlrpc' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--with-xsl=/opt/xslt/' '--with-zlib' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr'`

PHP Server API: `CGI/FastCGI`

Python Running as: `CGI`

> Hostgator does not support mod_python but I'm on a dedicated box, so I can modify the configs if I only knew how.. :)

Comment: Needs more info. Are both being served by the same Apache? How does PHP run, as an Apache module? How is Python set up?

Comment: Hi Pekka, I've updated the message with the details. From what I can see HG configures PHP using FastCGi and python is running as CGI not mod_python

Comment: `phpinfo()` will show the full HTTP headers (request & response). Does HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR appear there?

Comment: nope. phpinfo does not show the header. Somehow is seems php is stripping the HTTP_*_ headers for all requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using FastCGI. PHP isn't at ease with this, though it's making progress. With PHP 5.3 came php-fpm, *with 5.4 will come HTTP headers for FastCGI*. See the changelog of [apache_request_headers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php) or `getAllHeaders()`.

Though there's no pure PHP solution, the first note of the previous link contains a workaround: using mod_rewrite to set up environment variables.

```
# Apache config for mod_rewrite
# from callum85 at notspam dot msn dot com 19-Apr-2007 06:07
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR:%{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR}]
```

Comment: BTW, your question mentioned mod_python: this isn't recommended anymore. You probably should use mod_wsgi which implements [WSGI](http://wsgi.org/wsgi/).

Comment: thanks mate.. :) I've downgraded to php 4 for the scripts that need the http_*_ headers for now...